# objects as attributes in spring-data-solr document using converters

Tags: java, solr, solrj, spring-data-solr

I am using spring-data-solr to index my entities. As far as I understand, Solrj can handle [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) attribute but can't handle [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).

I tried to create and register custom converters following [this](http://lifelongprogrammer.blogspot.cz/2016/01/spring-solr-using-custom-converters-to.html) for conversion between [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) and String but it doesn't work. Moreover when I tried to use [org.joda.time.LocalDate](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) or [org.springframework.data.geo.Point](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/geo/class-use/Point.html) I have found that even converters specified in [org.springframework.data.solr.core.convert.SolrCustomConversions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-solr/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/solr/core/convert/SolrCustomConversions.html) do not work.

From the error response it seems like application tries to access core with name *localdate*.

Dependencies:

```
org.springframework.boot:1.5.3.RELEASE
org.springframework.data:spring-data-solr:2.1.3.RELEASE
org.apache.solr:solr-solrj:6.0.1
```

Code:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@SolrDocument(solrCoreName = "testentity")
public class SoTestEntity {

    @Field
    @Indexed
    private String id;

    @Field
    @Indexed(type = "daterange")
    private LocalDate localDateAttribute;
}

public final class TemporalConverters {
    @ReadingConverter
    public enum StringToLocalDateConverter implements Converter<String, LocalDate> {
        INSTANCE;

        @Override
        public LocalDate convert(String source) {
            return StringToLocalDateTimeConverter.INSTANCE.convert(source).toLocalDate();
        }
    }
    @WritingConverter
    public enum LocalDateToStringConverter implements Converter<LocalDate, String> {
        INSTANCE;

        @Override
        public String convert(LocalDate source) {
            if (source == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return source.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE);
        }
    }
}

public class SoTest {
    private SolrTemplate template;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    HttpSolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient("http://localhost:8983/solr");
    template = new SolrTemplate(client);
template.setSchemaCreationFeatures(Collections.singletonList(SolrPersistentEntitySchemaCreator.Feature.CREATE_MISSING_FIELDS));
    MappingContext mappingContext = new SimpleSolrMappingContext();
    MappingSolrConverter converter = new MappingSolrConverter(mappingContext);
    List<Converter> converters = new ArrayList<>();
    converters.add(TemporalConverters.LocalDateTimeToStringConverter.INSTANCE);
    converters.add(TemporalConverters.StringToLocalDateConverter.INSTANCE);
    converter.setCustomConversions(new CustomConversions(converters));
    template.setSolrConverter(converter);
    template.afterPropertiesSet();

    }

    @Test
    public void saveSingleTest() {
        template.saveBean(new SolrTestEntity());
    }
}
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.data.solr.UncategorizedSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/localdate/schema/version. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p>
</body>
</html>
; nested exception is org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/localdate/schema/version. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p>
</body>
</html>


    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.execute(SolrTemplate.java:224)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.schema.DefaultSchemaOperations.getSchemaVersion(DefaultSchemaOperations.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.schema.SolrSchemaWriter.retrieveSchemaVersion(SolrSchemaWriter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.schema.SolrSchemaWriter.isSchemaPresent(SolrSchemaWriter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.schema.SolrSchemaWriter.writeSchema(SolrSchemaWriter.java:41)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.schema.SolrPersistentEntitySchemaCreator.process(SolrPersistentEntitySchemaCreator.java:63)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.schema.SolrPersistentEntitySchemaCreator.onApplicationEvent(SolrPersistentEntitySchemaCreator.java:83)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.mapping.SolrMappingEventPublisher.publishEvent(SolrMappingEventPublisher.java:54)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:345)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:508)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:465)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:693)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:329)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:70)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.getSolrCoreOrBeanCollection(SolrTemplate.java:1300)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.saveBean(SolrTemplate.java:318)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.saveBean(SolrTemplate.java:300)
    at mypkg.SoTest.saveSingleTest(SoTest.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/localdate/schema/version. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p>
</body>
</html>

    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:545)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:241)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:230)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:149)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.schema.DefaultSchemaOperations$2.doInSolr(DefaultSchemaOperations.java:81)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.schema.DefaultSchemaOperations$2.doInSolr(DefaultSchemaOperations.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.execute(SolrTemplate.java:220)
    ... 42 more
```